# Usability Principles for Mobile App Design

Tags: usability, mobile, accessibility, design-principles

Have there been any principles developed for Mobile App designs? Any 'dos' vs. 'dont'? Any templates anyone can send me in the direction of?

Comment: This question is very general. You might be better to simply spend a few minutes searching the site -- there's already a lot of information here on these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Each platform has it's own general guidelines and specifics. Looking through some of them may give you an overall insight.

[Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

[iOS design guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[WP design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Great general answer to a general question.  ...maybe even enough to warrant allowing the question.